# Keyword 'ExcelLibrary.Open Excel Document' expected 3 arguments, got 2

Tags: excel, pycharm, robotframework

I need some help on this:
my Linux commands are set in Excel

My goal is execute this commands from Excel to a remote server

```
code001 echo "SELINUX=disabled" \> /etc/selinux/config
code002 timedatectl set-local-rtc no
code003 timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tokyo
code004 localectl set-locale LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
code005 echo "fs.suid_dumpable=2" \> /etc/sysctl.conf
code006 echo "Compress=no" \> /etc/sytemd/coredump.conf
code007 echo "DefaultLimitCORE" \> /etc/systemd/system.conf
code008 echo "d /var/lib/systemd/coredump 0755 root root 7d" \> /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf
```

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${EXCEL_FILE}     D:/dev/linuxcommands.xlsx
${SHEET_NAME}     Sheet1
${HOST}           192.168.100.117
${USERNAME}       root
${PASSWORD}       Hitokiri
${PORT}           22

*** Test Cases ***
Execute Excel Commands On Remote Server
    [Setup]    Open Excel Document    ${EXCEL_FILE}    ${SHEET_NAME} 
   mode=w
    ${ssh}    Open Connection    ${HOST}    port=${PORT}
    ${ssh}.Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    ${rows}=    Get Row Count    ${SHEET_NAME}
    :FOR    ${row}    IN RANGE    1    ${rows}
    \    ${command}=    Read Cell Data By Name    ${SHEET_NAME} 
   Command${row}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${command}' != ''    Execute Command On Remote Server    ${ssh}    ${command}
    [Teardown]    Close All Connections
```

now I append mode=w it resolve the issue but another error:

```
Execute Excel Commands On Remote Server                     | FAIL |
No keyword with name '${ssh}.Login' found.
```

but this error appears:

```
Execute Excel Commands On Remote Server                     | FAIL |
No keyword with name '${ssh}.Login' found.
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, and after I formatted your code, we can see that the keyword call for the Login is using `${ssh}.Login` instead of `SSHLibrary.Login`.

(What is the version of Robot Framework? That format of FOR stopped being used since version 3.2.1.)

Comment: Name: robotframework
Version: 7.0
Summary: Generic automation framework for acceptance testing and robotic process automation (RPA)
Home-page: https://robotframework.org
Author: Pekka Klärck
Author-email: peke@eliga.fi
License: Apache License 2.0

Comment: SSHLibrary.login   ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    ${rows}=    BuiltIn.Get Count     ${EXCEL_FILE}   ${SHEET_NAME}



I edit this portion: 


${ssh}.Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    ${rows}=    Get Row Count    ${SHEET_NAME}



and it works thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${EXCEL_FILE}     D:/dev/linuxcommands.xlsx
${SHEET_NAME}     Sheet1
${HOST}           192.168.100.117
${USERNAME}       root
${PASSWORD}       Hitokiri
${PORT}           22

*** Test Cases ***
Execute Excel Commands On Remote Server
    [Setup]    Open Excel Document    ${EXCEL_FILE}    ${SHEET_NAME}    mode=w
    ${ssh}    Open Connection    ${HOST}    port=${PORT}
    SSHLibrary.login   ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    ${rows}=    BuiltIn.Get Count     ${EXCEL_FILE}   ${SHEET_NAME}
    FOR    ${row}    IN RANGE    1    ${rows}
    \    ${command}=    Read Cell Data By Name    ${SHEET_NAME}
   Command${row}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${command}' != ''    Execute Command On Remote Server    ${ssh}    ${command}
    [Teardown]    Close All Connections
    END
```

Comment: You are now asking for another question, and this is not how Stack Overflow should be used. Please mark my answer as the solution, and search Internet for how to configure Jenkins.